# Scala Redis driver for high performance

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, redis

I need to develop a Scala based application that will write\read to\from managed AWS Redis at verry high rate. On official Redis page they mention several clients, without comparission. For my project every microsecond matters. I saw similar questions here, on SO, but they all are outdated.

Please advice what client has better performance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by client. For which programming language? What is the type of data you want to store? How often is it changing?

Comment: I mentioned that it's for scala :) I will put there values for keys. Data will be almost unchanged.

Comment: You can just use Jedis

Comment: @Lasf, will Jedis give better performance than scala-redis?

Comment: Given your requirements, I'd recommend benchmarking them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As another pointed out, you can use Jedis: https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/JedisPool.java

The latency may depend more on requesting within the same AZ/VPC (avoiding external networks) and using Redis pipelines, which batch together transactions and reduce number of requests. See pipeline usage examples here:

https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/AdvancedUsage

Here is another example combining AWS client libraries with Jedis:
https://github.com/fishercoder1534/AmazonElastiCacheExample/blob/master/src/main/java/AmazonElastiCacheExample.java